# Do the 90 Days on my VWP/ESTA pause when I am in Canada?

Tags: usa, canada, esta

I left the U.S. for Canada with about 3 weeks left on my stay allowance in the U.S. I am now wondering if the 90 days kept counting down while I was in Canada? I would like to visit some family on the way back over to Europe, but have the feeling that my 90 days have now expired. I am aware that Canada does not count towards a reset in allowance. Any help appreciated!

Comment: After some more research, I am quite sure that they have now expired. WOuld still appreciate some feedback though. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The 90 days do not pause in Canada, Mexico, or nearby islands. [Source](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visa-waiver-program.html) (Ctrl+F, "Trips to Canada, Mexico, or nearby Islands." When you come back to the US, your leave-by date is the same actual *date* as it was when you first entered the US; your whole trip, from when you first enter the US until you last leave the US, must be at most 90 days unless you left North America in the middle.

Comment: And just to clarify - nearby islands stands for *all* of Carribean islands/countries, including for example Aruba, Trinidad & Tobago, etc, which are not physically nearby :)